# Any changes made by using the GitHub Actions not reflecting into project files(Maven commands)

Tags: java, maven, github, github-actions

I'm developing a maven project and using GitHub Actions to build and deploy the package into GitHub. I'm using the maven command to update the version inside the workflow. Here is the workflow

```
name: Maven Package
on:
  push:
    branches: ['beta']
  release:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
          settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file

      - name: Semantic Version
        run: |
          mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.3.1-beta
          git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
          git config --global user.name <username>
          git config --global user.email <email>
          git add -A
          git commit -am "version beta update"
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ github.token }}
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages  Apache Maven
        run: mvn deploy -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/settings.xml
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

when I push the code to the beta branch. My workflow is changing the version and deploying the package, but it's not updating the version inside the pom.xml file. When I execute the command in the terminal it is updating the version inside pom.xml. But when I'm executing it by using Github Actions it is changing the version but not updating the pom file version and also not updating the target file. What should I do?
I need to change the version inside pom.xml using the GitHub-Actions workflow.

Thank you.

Comment: You are changing the code on GitHub but you don't commit the changes into Git back.

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, If I add commit and push commands, then `on push` will trigger again, and the whole process repeats continuously right?

Comment: you seemed to have a misunderstanding what a GitHub action actually is.. you have to make a commit in your git repository something like `git commit -am"Updated version` ...within the github action...

Comment: I tried it, now it's giving an error. 
`
Push to branch refs/heads/beta
remote: Permission to <username>/<repo>.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Invalid exit code: 128
`
the token has all permissions and it's working in locally

Comment: Which token is working? How are you using runner's token locally?

Comment: I'm using personal access token in my settings.xml file. Without push command in the github action workflow, it is working but when I add the push command it is showing the above error. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise. Now I'm able to update my pom.xml file. And also I solved the error while pushing by adding `persist-credentials: false, fetch-depth: 0`  to the workflow.